# What is the difference between creating fragment with a factory method and Fragment.instantiate?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi mate I am using pageview "JakeWharton-lib",
I saw an example on web, and in some example used factory method to create fragment.

```
  @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return TestFragment.newInstance(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length]);
    }
```

and in other example use Fragment.Instantiate(...)
what is the difference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newInstance` is not a part of Fragments API, it's a convenience helper method. It can have whatever signature is convenient in a particular case. Whereas `instantiate` is a part of API. It has a fixed signature.